# django 1.7 csrf_token not working: how is it supposed to work?

Tags: python, django

Page 1: Form with {% csrf_token %} in my template.

Page 2: Thanks page.

When I submit my form on Page 1 it uses HttpResponseRedirect to redirect to Page 2... so if the user refresh the page it will no be able to resubmit...

but I just noticed that if the user goes back in Page 2 to Page 1... He can press Submit button again an resubmit the same form... So... Is there a way to expire Page 1 when I show Page 2?

Just in case, my Middleware Classes are:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not what a CSRF token is meant to do, though technically you could regenerate the token and the user will see a `403 Forbidden` response when he tries to resubmit. A CSRF token should be just that, though - a token that prevents cross-site request forgery.

If a user should only be able to submit a form once, that should be handled in the form validation and checked against the database. Otherwise, going back and resubmitting the form is often considered an explicit action by the user and is handled the same as submitting a new form.

Answer (score -1):

CSRF token is designed to prevent other sites from posting content to your pages, thus prevent the creation of junk/spam records.

It is only designed for POST requests.

In order to prevent someone from writing a script that simply submits junk data to your pages, a unique token is generated using a secret key (which will not be known to the attacker).

On a legitimate request that comes from your site - your code generates a token using this key and sends it as part of the request.

The rogue request will not have this key, and your code will raise an appropriate error (thus preventing whatever action from taking place).

It is not designed to prevent legitimate, duplicate requests. There are two main ways to prevent this:

1. Make sure you always redirect after POST (this is to prevent someone hitting refresh and then sending the same request again; although almost all modern browsers will warn when doing so).
2. Control on the server side to prevent suspect duplicate entries.

Comment: That's not at all how a CSRF token works or what it's supposed to do. See [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/csrf/) and [how it works](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/csrf/#how-it-works).

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) also has a good explanation. Django supports both the "Synchronizer token pattern" and "Cookie-to-Header token" methods to prevent CSRF.

Comment: What I have written is exactly how it works - what you have linked to is the django-specific implementation of it. In that same page, _"This ensures that only forms that have originated from your Web site can be used to POST data back."_ which is the first line of my response _"CSRF token is designed to prevent other sites from posting content to your pages"_.

Comment: 'Not at all' was a bit strong now that I reread your answer, sorry for that. However, you make it sound like CSRF tokens prevent general spam/junk, and that's not what it does. A cross-site request forgery is an attack where a malicious website uses the visitor's authentication cookie to authenticate itself as that visitor. A CSRF token prevents that - and just that. Nothing prevents that malicious website from getting it's own token and submitting spam.

Comment: Actually, there is no element of authentication involved for CSRF.  It just prevents forged requested; even anonymous ones.

Comment: Technically not, no, tough it depends on what you would call authentication. If that's just the login mechanism, you're right. It only involves a request that uses the victim's IP, cookies or other information specific to that visitor on the targeted domain. Still, it is only a vulnerability if that user-specific information is in any way used to authenticate the identity of the user.

Comment: Actually no, you are not correct. It does not have to do with masquerading user credentials - it very simply has to do with preventing non genuine requests for POST.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70008/discussion-between-knbk-and-burhan-khalid).